# How to install Windows service without extending Installer?

Tags: .net, windows-services, installation

I am building a reusable [framework for building scheduling services](http://code.google.com/p/ncron/) using the .NET Framework. My code is distributed as a library, which is then referenced by the user in a console application. In the main entry point of the application, the user is asked to transfer control to a static method in the library, which will commence job scheduling if running in non-interactive mode, alternatively read command arguments and perform maintenance tasks such as installation.

In order to install the application as a Windows service using the `System.Configuration.Install` namespace, the user will have to add a class descendant of `Installer` to the application assembly, telling the framework how to install the service. I really would prefer to do this once and for all in the library, but unfortunately the installer class *has* to be in the application assembly.

The solution that I am looking at right now, involves defining the an installer class in the library, and requiring the user to inherit this in a public class, without adding any additional code. While this works, it requires the user to write annoying boiler plate code.

What are the alternatives to extending `Installer`?  Can I access the managed installation framework in more direct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [SC.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) to register the service binary.

Doing so leaves only this stub in the service installer class:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class SoapSenderInstaller : Installer
{
    public SoapSenderInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Calling SC.exe is a simple as this:

```
sc create MyService binpath= "C:\Path\to\my\MyService.exe" DisplayName= "My Service Display Name" depend= MSMQ start= auto
```

The only pitfall is the way sc.exe expects its commmand line arguments:

```
binpath=[BLANK]"MyService.exe"
```

**EDIT**

Of course this solution falls short to the requirement that user should not have to create any code that makes his binary a windows service because if he just references your library he would still need to inherit from ServiceBase and implement OnStart() and OnStop().

Comment: The installer class would still have to reside to in the entry assembly, not in a referenced library, right?

Comment: Yes, the installer class resides in the entry assembly but is practically empty. I did not yet try to complete omit the installer but maybe it would even be possible to so since it's only needed by InstallUtil.

Comment: Note that "sc.exe" is not available in Win2000 (not in default instalation, but may be installed with some tool-kit from MS)

Comment: After doing a bit of research and experiments, it appears to me that `sc` does not require an `Installer` to be present *at all*. As I understand it, `sc` does not even know/care if my binary is .NET or not. I guess this solves my problem.

Comment: +1. As a follow-up to kibab, how is SC.exe distributed? With what OS is it distributed? Filburt's link references some kind of resource kit, but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: @flipdoubt - SC.exe is available from XP and Windows 2003 upward as an "onboard tool". As kibab points out it is not available on Win2000 and downward - in this case you can obtain it from the respective platform resource kit.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can add some custom fields to installer and require user's input during installation if you compile it using  Installer.CodeEffects.com. May be, by requiring a namespace or type name as a string input from the end user, you could load or invoke things that you need on the fly at run time?

I can't think of anything else in your situation.